# Can't install pip because I get "the system cannot find the file specified" whenever I run get-pip.py (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, pip

So I'm running Python 2.7.11 and am trying to install pip. I thought pip was already installed on Python 2 >= 2.7.9, but I guess I was wrong. Whenever I try to run get-pip.py, I get:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp41xybl\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp41xybl\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp41xybl\pip.zip\pip\locations.py", line 120, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp41xybl\pip.zip\pip\utils\appdirs.py", line 150, in site_config_dirs
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp41xybl\pip.zip\pip\utils\appdirs.py", line 191, in _get_win_folder_from_registry
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, and there aren't any helpful answers online. Can someone help me understand what I need to do to fix this and get pip installed? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to run the command prompt as admin?

Comment: Yes and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Could this have to do with where I installed Python 2.7 or where get-pip.py is located?

Comment: yes sure, you probably have to add the python.exe to your path, and go into the directory that you downloaded the get-pip.py file from the command prompt

Comment: I have done both of those things already, and they didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: I know this is very old at this point, but I wanted to report my own attempts required that I run pip install with the `--user` argument.  All errors went away after that.